# How to apply a material on a GLTFLoader loaded model?

Tags: three.js

I have the following snippet of code that loads the Xbot.glb model (copied from the three.js examples). When i load and render this model it appears to be reddish in color. My goal is to simply change the material. So i tried the following code below.

```
var loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('/models/Xbot.glb', function (gltf) {

                gltf.scene.scale.set(150, 150, 150);

                gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
                    if (child.isMesh) {
                        log('Apply model material');
                        child.castShadow = true;
                        child.material = floorMaterial; // Commenting this line works. The model is red.
                    }
                });

                scene.add(gltf.scene);
```

Floor material:

```
floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xeeeeee, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 40 });
```

Unfortunately now the model does not appear. Note that the floorMaterial is being saved and is being used to apply a grayish material to the floor (PlaneGeometry).

What do i need to do to apply a material to a loaded GLB model. Note that ive seen similar posts here on S.O. Some of them seem identical to the issue im seeing. But none of the solutions seem to work.

Comment: Can we see some more of your code? How do you initialize `floorMaterial`? Is `Xbot.glb` the correct filename? Earlier on you mentioned `Xbox`, not `Xbot`.

Comment: Added the floorMaterial creation code. the "XBox" was simply a typo.